# Module '"firebase/app"' has no exported member 'auth'

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to connect to firebase to do Google authentication on the app.

But when I try to do:

```
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';
```

I get weird error:

Module '"firebase/app"' has no exported member 'auth'.

I would love to call GoogleAuthProvider method on auth property.

Thank you so much for your help!

I experimented with packages but nothing helped :(

Comment: Looks like you're using the wrong import.  Check out [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#add-initialize-sdk)

Comment: If you want to work with Firebase you should checkout Angular Fire: https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/angular/angularfire2/
From the docs: 
`AngularFire smooths over the rough edges an Angular developer might encounter when implementing the framework-agnostic Firebase JS SDK & aims to provide a more natural developer experience by conforming to Angular conventions.`

Comment: And for authentication with Firebase, you can start here : https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md